# Were the lure towns in Wall Maria evacuated?

Tags: attack-on-titan

I was re watching season 1 because season 2 started airing not to long ago. As I watched it got me thinking.

With the lure towns in Wall Maria, 1 out of 4 got breached but the other 3 were in theory safe. Did they get evacuated or did they stay in those lure parts of the wall? because even if they stayed they wouldn't have much food.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As the Wiki specifies](http://attackontitan.wikia.com/wiki/Walls#History) (my apologies; I'm too lazy to look up specific manga chapters page by page):

> Shiganshina District was the first city to fall when Wall Maria was
>   breached, leading to a massive slaughter and **prompting humanity to
>   abandon the entire perimeter and the remaining cities along the Wall**
>   as they attempted to consolidate their losses. After the fall of Wall
>   Maria, humanity was pushed into Wall Rose.

So yes, they are empty. Probably not as damaged as Shiganshina but considering most of the loss in human lives was due the insufficiency of evacuation vacancies, it's fair to say, people might have met a slower and more prolongued, but equally bloody, end as those in Shiganshina.

Comment: thank you for the comment ill check this as right answer becouse ur right i couldnt find it on the wiki but with the quote I found it. ill vote up as support :).

Comment: It's linked right on the word 'wiki'. I'll edit it so the link encompasses more, perhaps it wasn't very clear.

Answer (score 1):

The government decided that they were a lost cause, the narrator said so in Season 1 Episode 2.

Comment: oke. thx for the answer!